# wordpress in apache subdirectory get 404

Tags: wordpress, apache

I was trying to host a wordpress site in a sub-directory of my site. I use apache so I edited the 000-default.conf file with adding the following:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/html/wordpress
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I restart the server, and go to the site, say "example.com/blog", it shows a broken wordpress, with all the 404 errors for the ".js" files. It tried to look for them in the root site (example.com). Question is: how can I set it for the subdirectory site look for its files in example.com/blog?

For further information, my root host is a Symfony site (not a wordpress), and I'm running a AWS EC2 ubuntu server.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Moving_a_Root_install_to_its_own_directory

Comment: Thank you Jack. That is the right tutorial to follow. But I just figured out there is one more step to do to prevent the publishing of the page giving a 404: Add the following two lines in wp-config.php:   define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the apache2 mod_rewrite module. You can do it by running the following command:

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**